# How to Write a apex class to get the json input Values from postman

Tags: apex, apexrest, post

In PostMan the Request Body look Like this :

```
{"eventitems":[{
    "whatid":"0012800000i92pd",
    "whoid":"0032800000TirUN",
    "OwnerId":"005280000010olH",
    "IsAllDayEvent":true,
    "Subject":"call",
    "StartDate":"2016-07-01T14:00:00.000+0000",
    "EndDate":"2016-07-01T15:00:00.000+0000",
    "Recurrence":true,
    "Recurrencestdate":"2016-07-01T10:00:00.000+0000",
    "Recurrenceenddate":"2016-07-02",
    "RecType":"RecursDaily",
    "Recintrvl":"1",
    "Invitees":["0032800000TiE8N"]
},

{

    "whatid":"0012800000KQTwd",
    "whoid":"0032800000MLsdL",
    "OwnerId":"005280000010olH",
    "IsAllDayEvent":true,
    "Subject":"call",
    "StartDate":"2016-07-01T14:00:00.000+0000",
    "EndDate":"2016-07-01T15:00:00.000+0000",
    "Recurrence":true,
    "Recurrencestdate":"2016-07-01T10:00:00.000+0000",
    "Recurrenceenddate":"2016-07-02",
    "RecType":"RecursDaily",
    "Recintrvl":"1",
    "Invitees":["0032800000MLmNd"]
}
]
}
```

How to Get the json input in apex class,i Have tried the following code :

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/create Event/')
 global  with sharing class  CreateEventClass
  {
  @Httppost
  global static string CreateEvent()
    {
         RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
         RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
         Blob body = req.requestBody;
         string body1=body.tostring();
         system.debug(body1);
         Map<String,object> mp = (Map<String,object>)JSON.deserializeUnTyped(body1);
         system.debug(mp);
 eventitems name =(eventitems)json.deserialize(JSON.serialize(mp.get('eventitems')),eventitems.class);
         system.debug(name);
Last two lines showing Error
[
  {
    "errorCode": "APEX_ERROR",
    "message": "System.JSONException: Malformed JSON: Expected '{' at the beginning of object\n\nClass.System.JSON.deserialize: line 15, column 1\nClass.CreateEventClass.CreateEvent: line 24, column 1"
  }
]
```

How to Rectify the Error

Comment: Create wrapper class to catch entire structure (with eventitems itself) and use that for deserialization

Comment: Yes I have Created the Wrapper Class and then only I am Trying

Comment: Please Guide Me For the Answer

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a Apex class with https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/ and deserialize it.

```
JSON2Apex jsnApx = (JSON2Apex)JSON.deserialize(body1, JSON2Apex.class);
system.debug('@@@ = '+jsnApx.whatid);
system.debug('@@@ = '+jsnApx.whoid);
...
```

Wrapper Class

```
//
// Generated by JSON2Apex http://json2apex.herokuapp.com/
//

public class JSON2Apex {

    public List<Eventitems> eventitems;

    public class Eventitems {
        public String whatid;
        public String whoid;
        public String OwnerId;
        public Boolean IsAllDayEvent;
        public String Subject;
        public String StartDate;
        public String EndDate;
        public Boolean Recurrence;
        public String Recurrencestdate;
        public String Recurrenceenddate;
        public String RecType;
        public String Recintrvl;
        public List<String> Invitees;
    }


    public static JSON2Apex parse(String json) {
        return (JSON2Apex) System.JSON.deserialize(json, JSON2Apex.class);
    }
}
```